# Elasticsearch aggregation min-max gives "illegal_argument_exception"

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

This is data, want to find min and max on "apiCallTime" field.

[image: JSON]

When I query for same, getting the following exception
[image]

with field_name.keyword which leads to another error
[image]

Can someone help me with solving?

Comment: Make sure you field has correct type (checking index/type mapping) https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html

Comment: @OlegAndreyev field has correct datetime type

Comment: Okay, trying adding format to aggregation https://discuss.elastic.co/t/min-date-and-max-date/125174

Comment: @OlegAndreyev after adding format also it is showing same exception

Comment: Add mapping of index to question. Also please don't add images, instead add the code so that it is easy for people to copy and replicate the issue you are facing.